# How do I automate tasks in EmEditor?

Tags: automation, tasks, workflow, text-processing, emeditor

Does EmEditor have a way to automate a workflow? My workflow involves a sequence of commands that could easily be automated if there was a way to do so.

Comment: I wanted to create the tag `emeditor` for this question but I do not have 300 reputation. Could someone create this tag for me? EmEditor is a text editor app. If you search for [`emeditor`](https://superuser.com/search?q=emeditor), you can see that there are a lot of questions already. We anticipate more questions to be asked about EmEditor on this site. Although [SO has this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emeditor), Super User is a better suited since the questions are primarily about the app and not programming.

Comment: I see there is a `Notepad++` tag on SU so this does seem appropriate for `emeditor`

Answer (score 2):

The macro feature in EmEditor can automate a series of steps that otherwise need to be done manually. A macro is a JavaScript file that automates a sequence of EmEditor commands. If you have a task that requires a lot of clicking in EmEditor, a macro may reduce the amount of manual labor required.

To get started on a macro, you can record which buttons you click on in EmEditor, which will be written to a macro.

1. Go to Macros | Start/Stop Record (or click on the Start Recording button in the toolbar).

[image: Toolbar]

2. Now select the commands that you want to record in the macro. Click on Start/Stop Record or Stop Recording in the toolbar when you are done.
3. Go to Macros | Edit (or Edit Macro in the toolbar). It opens a macro showing the series of commands that you called. Here is an example of a macro which sorts, replaces a string, selects all, then deletes.

```javascript
document.Sort("A+",eeSortBinaryComparison | eeSortIgnorePrefix,"en-US");
document.selection.Replace("a","d",eeReplaceAll,0);
document.selection.SelectAll();
document.selection.Delete(1);
```

4. Save the macro as a `.jsee` file.
5. Select the macro to run with Macros | Select... and open the `.jsee` file to run. Then run the macro with Macros | Run [yourMacro].jsee (or Run Macro in the toolbar).

You can now edit the `.jsee` macro for complex tasks with variables, loops, functions, etc. The newer [v8 engine](https://www.emeditor.com/faq/macros-faq/how-do-i-use-the-v8-engine/) can be used for the latest ECMAScript features.

See the [macros documentation](https://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_index.html) for all available functions for interacting with EmEditor. Some commands are not available as named functions but can be called with [`editor.ExecuteCommandByID()`](https://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_editor_editor_executecommandbyid.html) by passing the command ID listed on every command page. For example, the [Open command](https://www.emeditor.org/en/cmd_file_file_open.html) is `editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4097);`.

## Input and output

There are many ways to input and output information.

For inputting, you may get the selected text in the document as a string with [`document.selection.Text`](https://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_selection_selection_text.html). You can display an input control with `var input = prompt("message", "", 0);`.

To output information, you can write to the current document with `document.selection.Text = "text";` You can write a short message to the status bar with [`status = "Status text";`](https://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_window_window_status.html). You can display a dialog box with `alert("Task complete.")`.